# Getting two USB devices to run on different buses

Tags: usb, 14.04, hardware, webcam

My objective is to get two webcams streaming simultaneously on my computer. Because of [bandwidth limitations of the uvcvideo driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227498/set-webcam-on-different-usb-bus) (or see bottom of [UVC faq](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/)), I need the two webcams to be on different buses.

However, try as I might, no matter which ports I plug my usb webcams into, they both run on Bus 01. Likewise, my usb mouse always runs on Bus 03.

Output of `lspci | grep -i usb`

```
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #1 (rev 09)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #2 (rev 09)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #3 (rev 09)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset UHCI USB Controller #4 (rev 09)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 631xESB/632xESB/3100 Chipset EHCI USB2 Controller (rev 09)
```

Output of `lsusb` with nothing plugged in:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Output of `lsusb` with a mouse and one webcam plugged in:

```
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 046d:0843 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Output of `lsusb` with a webcam plugged in where the mouse was:

```
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 045e:076f Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 046d:0843 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

How can I get my webcams to operate on different usb buses?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but what is the reason you want to do this? Are are trying to solve a particular problem?

Comment: Yep! I have a problem similar to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227498/set-webcam-on-different-usb-bus?rq=1) user. Both webcams have a bandwidth of 480 mbps, so I cannot stream from them concurrently on a single usb hub.

Comment: Looks like you might have only one USB2.0, the rest being USB 1.1, which would not be fast enough for your camera.

Comment: Oh, why isn't USB 1.1 fast enough for a 480 mbps camera?

Comment: @Jamie, USB1.1 has 12 Mbit/s (Full Bandwidth or Full Speed). Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#1.1